# Строку в словарь, ключи без кавычек

Tags: python, json, dict

Есть строка вида

```
'{status:"ok", status_p:{id:"0", name:"123", update:{day:"06.05.2021", time:"11:55"}}}'
```

хотелось бы её преобразовать в словарь. Попробовал через replace расставить двойные кавычки в нужных местах. Помогло, но код выглядит выглядит громоздко и не красиво. Может всё такие в json есть какой-то метод для таких строк?

Comment: Это не json, поэтому нет

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24027589

Answer (score 0):

```
exec("a = " + '{"key1" : 1, "key2" : 2, "key3" : 3}')
print(type(a))

# Вывод: <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: На строке из вопроса это не сработает